# How to add Chains feature of constraint layout with design in android studio

Tags: android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I have two images in constraint layout. I want to use chains feature with design page in android studio but I can't find icon or menu that represent Chains feature.

Comment: check out [this article](http://androidweekly.us2.list-manage1.com/track/click?u=887caf4f48db76fd91e20a06d&id=c32c1ec0f1&e=2e4d18d86e)

Comment: Thanks!! @Beloo But still doesn't work. Two images move in design but attribute app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf and chains link not created in xml

Comment: Chains Feature was recently added in the latest alpha in the Canary Channel, otherwise you just have to do it in code (which is still a good idea to understand  how it works).

Answer (score 10):

### Update (2019 august 23)

The small buttons shown on the screenshots are now available on the right click menu, Google updated the UI for more easy layout operations.

### How to add Chains feature of `ConstraintLayout` with Android Studio's 'Layout Editor'?

The chain style can be controlled by "chain" button right below the view:

[image]

Click on it few times to toggle between all 3 modes:

**spread** (the default one)

[image]

**spread_inside**

[image]

**packed**

[image]

Let's see some examples

### centering views which are connected together using chain

1. drag and drop three buttons into the Android Studio's 'Layout Editor'

[image]

2. Select those buttons together by dragging mouse

[image]

3. Pack them vertically using the 'pack' button in 'Layout Editor'

[image]

4. Align them center horizontally using 'Align-Center horizontally' button

[image]

5. Align them center vertically using the 'Align-Center vertically' button

[image]

---

Here we used the `pack` `option`. similar to this, you can try `spread` and `spread inside` options of `chain` to see the difference. cheers :)

---

Comment: I don't know but the little buttons is are not shown with me, do you have an idea how to show them

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim I am not seeing the little buttons either. Have you figured out how to get them to display?

Comment: @DavidB in the latest versions they moved to the right click menu

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim Ah, okay. Thank you. It would be nice if Google kept their documentation up-to-date a little better. The few things I found in their documentation all used the old UI.

Answer (score 2):

1. First put two images horizontally.
   [image: Two horizontal images]
2. Select both of them with the left click of the mouse.
   [image: Selected Images]
3. Then press center horizontal form toolbar.

[image: center horizontal]

4. The chain is served.

[image: Chain done]

Similarly, you can create the vertical chain.[image: vertical images][image][image]